# power point template

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, power

I am looking for a circular power point menu template, something that looks like [this](http://www.presentationmagazine.com/circular-powerpoint-menu-template-1568.htm):

What is this template like this called? Do you guys have any recommendation where to look one for free?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard to create such a template yourself or modify another template to contain a radial progress indicator. Start by creating the base frame with a circle object and lines going out to boxes or other circles. Label each object. Now duplicate the slide as many times as needed. Last, go to each of the duplicated slides and bold the text on the active item you're about to cover or perhaps change the background color like in the example you provided.